# How does Xen handle non-virtualizable instructions in user space code?

Tags: intel, virtualization, xen, hypervisor

Xen has to handle [non-virtualizable instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32794361/what-are-non-virtualizable-instructions-in-x86-architecture/32797308) in the Guest OS kernel code.

But what if my user-space code contains such instructions (e.g., SGDT that stores the GDT info into memory)? Can my code still runs smoothly in a guest VM with Xen para-virtualization? Will it reveal the host's GDT info (and thus become some concern)?

Besides, can anybody show me the code/details how SGDT (and other non-virtualizable instructions) in the guest kernel is handled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://xenbits.xen.org/docs/xtf/test-umip.html

Seems that this was indeed a vulnerability until the new CPU feature:

User-Mode Instruction Prevention (UMIP) is a feature present in new Intel Processors.

When active, it causes the SGDT, SIDT, SLDT, STR and SMSW instructions to yield #GP when executed with CPL > 0. This prevents userspace applications from obtaining sensitive operating system information.

=================================================================

Seems that people from the security community take this seriously:
[On the Cutting Edge: Thwarting Virtual Machine Detection, 2006](http://handlers.sans.org/tliston/ThwartingVMDetection_Liston_Skoudis.pdf)